# adding constraints to decorator pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, constraints, decorator

In the decorator pattern, I've been looking at the coffee shop example. I understand how it works, but I was wondering if for some reason only one decorator was allowed at a time, how would you implement the constraint?

Comment: What is the "coffee shop example"? Without more information, it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, I presumed from the popularity of it that it was well known. Beverage is the Concrete Decorator, different coffees like HouseBlend/DarkRoast are the Concrete Components, There is a Condiment Decorator which is Decorator, and the Concrete Decorators are thinks like Milk or Mocha. My question is, if you were only allowed one Concrete Decorator, eg Milk, but no Mocha or vice versa, how would this best be implemented?

Comment: Write an aggregate decorator?

Comment: how do you mean exactly?

Comment: Is this homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211309/decorator-method-one-decorator-type-in-java/22232464#22232464

Comment: An aggregate decorate would be something that takes a list of other decorator objects & a decorated objects & hooks them all together.